# Whether AWS Elasticsearch 6.2 kurumoji plugin support user dictionary

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-elasticsearch

In my appliction I am using **AWS Elasticsearch service version 6.2**.

In this version I have installed kurumoji plugin to support Japanese string.

I need to use user_dictionary for few Japanese strings.

Whether AWS Elasticsearch (Kurumoji) have "**user_dictionary**" support?

**If yes where to put *user_dictionary* file in aws elasticsearch ?**

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately AWS does not provide user dictionary for Elasticsearch service.

If it's necessary, build Elasticsearch cluster on EC2 instances.